# Data too large to do calculation after calculation

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

```
   TailNum  Year year 
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
 1 N605AW   2006 1997 
 2 N309AW   2006 1990 
 3 N104UW   2006 1999 
 4 N162UW   2006 2001 
 5 N665AW   2006 2001 
 6 N659AW   2006 2000 
 7 N837AW   2006 2005 
 8 N751UW   2006 2000 
 9 N770UW   2006 2000 
10 N746UW   2006 2000
```

I am trying to get **Year col to minus year col to get age col**.

I've tried:

```
#convert years to numeric  
df_tailnum <- df_tailnum %>%
  unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% 
  as.numeric(df_tailnum$year)

#find age of planes
df_tailnum$Age <- df_tailnum["Year"] - df_tailnum["year"]
```

But my result will turn out to be too large for me to do anything else
[data: large list 1.GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZdNb.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a simpler way for me to get the result?

Steps so far:

```
> #find manufacturing date of planes 
> df_tailnum <- inner_join(df_tailnum, select(df_planes, tailnum, year), by = c(TailNum = "tailnum")) %>%
+   drop_na() %>% 
+   filter(year != "0") %>% 
+   filter(year != "0000") %>% 
+   filter(year != "none") %>% 
+   filter(year != "None")
> head(df_tailnum)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  TailNum  Year year 
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 N605AW   2006 1997 
2 N309AW   2006 1990 
3 N104UW   2006 1999 
4 N162UW   2006 2001 
5 N665AW   2006 2001 
6 N659AW   2006 2000 
> dim(df_tailnum)
[1] 5951272       3
> #convert years to numeric  
> df_tailnum <- df_tailnum %>%
+   unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% 
+   as.numeric(df_tailnum$year)
Warning message:
In df_tailnum %>% unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% as.numeric(df_tailnum$year) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> head(df_tailnum)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
> dim(df_tailnum)
NULL
```

Comment: Can you please show the dimensions of the data frame / tibble ?

Comment: In fact, the code could be much simpler like in my answer

Comment: i tried is_tibble(df_tailnum) and it return FALSE 

I've no idea what I done wrong. 

Btw how do I add code blocks into comments?

Comment: According to the image you attached is a list. But the first block shows a tibble and your is_tibble()  functions returns FALSE. That is too much haha

can you show me the results of head(df_tailnum) and also dim(df_tailnum)

Comment: I've made changes to my post on my steps so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete this:

```
df_tailnum <- df_tailnum %>%
+   unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% 
+   as.numeric(df_tailnum$year)
Warning message:
In df_tailnum %>% unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% as.numeric(df_tailnum$year) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> head(df_tailnum)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
> dim(df_tailnum)
```

And use this:

```
df_tailnum$Age <- df_tailnum$Year - as.numeric(df_tailnum$year)
```

Alternative:

```
df_tailnum$year <- df_tailnum %>%
    unlist(df_tailnum$year) %>% 
    as.numeric(df_tailnum$year)
```

Comment: omg it worked! haha but why? what did I do wrong?

Comment: You were updating the entire data set instead of just one column when converting

Comment: I added an alternative, but I don't recommend it, because it's unnecessary coding vs simple and refactored code

Comment: you mean unlist(df_tailnum$year) was applied to the entire data set?

Comment: I mean the assignation: "<-"